# Marketing Cloud : Deleting single send journeys

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We use Marketing cloud to send emails to our customers with an attachment.

All our journeys are "Single Send" and to 500-3000 customers.

As part of housekeeping/maintenance, after 24 hours of the journey, we "delete" the journey.

Before performing the journey "delete", we ensure that the status of the journey is always "Sent" .

After the delete operation, the journey status becomes "Cancelled" as shown below.

[image]

Do ignore the second item from the image as it was a test run.

Is that approach fine ?

Would a period of 24 hours is enough for marketing cloud to send around 500-3000 emails (with max of 2 attachments ...each with size less than 100kb) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach looks fine to me, and you should not be worried about send performance. Journey Builder should actually be able to process up to [2 million email sends per hour](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_optimize_sending_in_journey_builder.htm&type=5).

The only activity which might take more than 24 hours is sending to email addresses which bounce. As [described here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_bounce_mail_management.htm&type=5), when a soft bounce happens, the system retries sending the email to the subscriber every 15 minutes for 72 hours, for up to 288 tries. Only after the system stops attempting to retry does a subscriber appear in your tracking as Bounced.

I do believe, however, that deleting the actual single send journey should not affect this, since the actual retries are happing in a different part of MC than JB. But, if you want to be 100% safe, I might extend the deletion window from 24 to 72 hours.